# Illuminated fraction of Moon's surface ratio question

Tags: trigonometry, ratio

[image]

On page 345 of *Astronomical Algorithms* by Meeus, he states that the illuminated fraction $k$ of the Moon's disk is given by the ratio $BC:AC$ (see diagram) where $BC$ is the width of the illuminated crescent and $AC$ is the Moon's diameter. He then goes on to say that this is the same ratio as the crescent's *area* ($NCSB$) to the total disk *area* ($NCSA$). The illuminated fraction is given by

$$k=\frac{1+\cos i}{2},$$where $i$ is the phase angle, the angle between the Sun and Earth as seen from the centre of the Moon. Now, I can understand (and derive) why $k$ is the ratio of the lengths $BC:AC$, but I cannot see why it is also the ratio of the areas. I've looked at the (complicated, to my eyes) formula for the area of a lune (a crescent shape), given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)#:%7E:text=In%20plane%20geometry%2C%20the%20crescent,bounded%20by%20two%20circular%20arcs.) and can't make the link between it and the total disk area. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$NBS$ is not a part of circle but a half on an ellipse with semiaxes $ON$ and $OB$. The rest is trivial knowing the expression for the ellipse area

Comment: Brilliant. I was assuming $NBS$ is part of a circle. It's half of an ellipse because the diameter of the illuminated circle of the Moon is not perpendicular to Earth, and a squashed circle is an ellipse. Correct? So there's no need for the complicated lune area formula. I would never have seen that.

Comment: The border line of the illuminated part of the Moon (which is a semi-sphere) is in fact a circle with the normal directed to the Sun. This normal makes an angle with the sight direction -  therefore we observe it as an ellipse (more precisely as a half of ellipse because the other half is on the opposite side of the Moon).